# How to control output file name in a batch file?

Tags: batch-file, ffmpeg

I'm running a batch file to use FFMPEG to convert all the files with the *.MTS extension in a directory.

```
for %%A in (*.MTS) do ffmpeg -i "%%A" -vcodec copy -acodec pcm_s16le -ar 48000 -ac 2 "newfiles\%%A.mov"
pause
```

The output files go to a directory called newfiles. The conversion takes place with no problem. The problem is that if the input is a file name.MTS the output is a file name.MTS.mov

How can i change the batch file so that with an input of name.MTS the output is name.mov?

Comment: "newfiles\%%~nA.mov"

Comment: Helps if you read the documentation for the commands you are trying to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to normal `for` loop variables, you can also use additional syntax to change the output. From the output of `for /?`:

```
%~I         - expands %I removing any surrounding quotes (")
%~fI        - expands %I to a fully qualified path name
%~dI        - expands %I to a drive letter only
%~pI        - expands %I to a path only
%~nI        - expands %I to a file name only
%~xI        - expands %I to a file extension only
%~sI        - expanded path contains short names only
%~aI        - expands %I to file attributes of file
%~tI        - expands %I to date/time of file
%~zI        - expands %I to size of file
```

So in your case, you would use `newfiles\%%~nA.mov`